# Validating password and email

Tags: php, forms, webforms

I would like to validate password in password field with say minimum 6 characters and maximum 12. and also it should be alphanumeric character. how can I validate the same with PHP?? and also need to validate email too..

Comment: Setting maximum password lengths and restricting the type of characters that you can enter is both poor form and poor security.  Please reconsider having anything other than a minimum length!

Comment: How could that be?? an alphanumeric character is very tough to break..isn't it??

Comment: If I was going to bruteforce your password, I may have (example) 255  characters to test. If you limit it to alphanumeric, I have 62 characters to test (I think).

Comment: I don't recommend setting a maximum for password fields. A minimum length for a password is fine, but it should in no way have a maximum limit. So you could say I recommend you not having one.

Answer (score 1):

Validating a password is often a weird thing to do, because your storage should be hashed or encrypted, so you never actually see the original password (thus why limiting character ranges and maximum length is unnecessary).

Limiting it to these characters will only make cracking them easier (subset of characters to test).

You can validate that using a regular expression.

```
preg_match('/^\w{6,12}$/', $str);
```

(this allows underscores (`_`) as well).

A *better* validating would be a minimum length (8 chars in this example) and perhaps a non alphanumeric character, which would be...

```
strlen($str) >= 8 AND preg_match('/\W/', $str)
```

You can validate an email using...

```
filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: @aron Assuming `$str` above are the relevant user entered inputs. If you don't understand this, you should ask a question *How to get user input in PHP and validate it?*. I'm sure there are many questions already on here similar to that that can help you.

Comment: the action of the form should be the url where the php code to test this is running.  You should at least md5 the password for security purposes.

Comment: oh I was confused it give in 1 or 0 but it isnt checking whether password contains numbers. even if numbers are not there and is above 6 chars then it is accepting why??

Comment: The form's method should be set to `POST` and action to a separate PHP file. `$_POST` the specific fields and validate them. From there, do what you wish. Redirect them back to the previous page with an error or bring them to the next page. Seeing as how you are asking a basic question, I'd avoid any form of Javascripting and/or other more complicated actions that you could do.

Comment: @Syed Abdul Rahman why you should redirect it?? you can validate the same on the same page itself??

Comment: @alex your regular expression for passwords also allows a trailing newline (`$` vs `\z`) - not that that's a bad thing, just thought I'd point it out since you mentioned the underscore.

Comment: @Long Ears Thanks for pointing that out, as I didn't know about it. :)

Comment: @alexa but my boss need something this way - passd50al26

Comment: @aron Fair enough, so long as the boss is responsible when the passwords are cracked for being a low hanging fruit :P

Comment: @alex I dont know but then what you suggest...then which one is strong passsword??? I got confused

Comment: @aron if you want to enforce that it contains a number then to adapt Alex's code, `strlen($str) >= 8 && preg_match('/\d/', $str)`. I'd highly recommend his check for `\W` (a non-alphanumeric character) too.

Comment: If you want to validate it on the same page itself, you have to use Javascript, namely AJAX or JQuery. The `keyup` function works well. Even so, you have to direct it to a different page. This page's sole purpose is validation. Doing it on the same page means it would have to run everything; from the CSS to the navigational bars and everything in it all over again. EDIT: You could also add this into your input field to limit it to a maximum of 12 - `maxlength = "12"`

Comment: @Syed That doesn't stop me from posting an arbitrary string to your server.

Comment: Add or Strip slashes from usernames and passwords. md5 them afterwards. That solves some problems all on its own.